# How to convert dd-mon-yyyy dates to dd-mm-yyyy in python

Tags: python-2.7, date

I want to convert dates in dd-mon-yyyy formats to dd-mm-yyyy in python. Is there any libraries that can directly do this.

Comment: Take a look at `datetime`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`datetime` library with little bit customization might help:

```
from datetime import datetime
date_input = raw_input('Enter a date in dd-mon-yyyy format: ')
date_obj = datetime.strptime(date_input, '%d-%b-%Y')
print date_obj.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
```

---

Reference:

For more customization please have a look onto http://strftime.org/